# Cannot Connect to AWS RDS Oracle using sql developer

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to AWS RDS Oracle using SQL developer but I keep getting this error:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=M+x/Vg6EQDCP81wjiVlKwA==)

I tried many ways to connect to my DB but I could not. Please can someone help me?

I'm a developer trying to test things out.

Below are the screenshots of my config:

[image: Connectivity & security]

[image: Configuration]

[image: Inbound rules]

Comment: Can you share your connection string or values like the hostname, sid, etc, you are using in the sqldeveloper to connect to the database?

Comment: You can also try adding or editing an inbound rule in the security group. For Source, choose My IP. This allows access to the DB instance from the IP address detected in your browser.

Comment: Thanks @ArpitJain I tried your way and all the other ways. I'm going to give up this and stick to mongoDB. I've been trying to do this a month. Thankss again

Comment: This is part of developer life and this is how you learn, you shouldn't give up, Let me know if i can help out :)

Comment: @ArpitJain ok do you check for an issue over a month. I've been checking for a solution more than a month